# Парсинг на php

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте, вопрос у меня такой.

Мой сайт парсит чужой сайт, какая информация остается на чужом сайте (лог или статистика) о действии моего скрипта (сайта)? Можно ли как-то скрывать такую инфу? Может ли сайт, который я парсю, как-то меня "прикрыть" в плане доступа к своим страницам?

Если где-то есть инфа на эту тему, дайте ссылочку.

Answer (score 2):

Генерируйте случайный юзер-агент (можно рандомить и другие поля запроса) и пользуйтесь проксями, тогда вам никто ничего не сделает.

И советую пользоваться голыми сокетами, простора больше.

Минимальный код для сокетов:

```
$e1 = $e2 = false;
if ($s = fsockopen( gethostbyname('bash.org.ru'), 80, $e1, $e2, 5 /* сек таймаут соединения */)) { // открываем соединение
  @fwrite($s, 
     "GET /quote/22722 HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    ."Host: bash.org.ru\r\n"
    ."User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.9) Gecko/20100824 Firefox/3.6.9 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 4.0.20506)\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ); // шлем запрос
  $content = '';
  do {
    stream_set_timeout($s, 1);
    $str = @fread($s, 1024);
    $content .= $str;      
    } while (strlen($str) == 1024); // читаем ответ
  fclose($s); // закрываем соединение
  }
```

Эта штука тырит цитату 22722 с баша. Вам для переделки нужно найти (идем в google) "как послать запрос через http-прокси", "[список строк User-Agent](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Agent)" (и рандомить их), "бесплатные http proxy список", ну и вообще поля GET/POST запросов.

Answer (score 1):

Специальных логов как таковых нет, потому что Ваш скрипт делает GET запрос (хотя не лишне было бы указать как Вы это делаете) и не более того. Другое дело, если владелец того сайта обратит внимание на referrer, и то, если он сам предусмотрел логгинг, либо на страницах установлен счетчик от какого-нибудь провайдера такого сервиса.
Другое дело, если он закрыл типы файлов (такие как mp3 например) с помощью того же .htaccess от прямого линкования, то тогда Вам надо призадуматься о целесообразности "грабления". Грубо говоря, "сайт-жертва" может предпринять меры, ну только если его админ-владелец-прочее предпримет меры, причем грамотные, та же фильтрация частоты запросов по IP, например.

Comment: я использую CURL 
приблизительно вот так 

<?php
        $ch = curl_init("http://exmaple.com");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);      
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $output;

?>

Comment: Что Вам желательно узнать? Приемы на стороне, которые могут использовать против "грабления"?